# Android NDK ndk-build helloJni error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk

i am trying to run HelloJni program form NDK samples.I am using eclipse juno. Alos the ".so" file is not being generated. But while ndk-build the project i get the following message in my console:

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project HelloJni ****

/home/ethics-14/android-ndk/ndk-build all 
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-19 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 10 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
[arm64-v8a] Gdbserver      : [aarch64-linux-android-4.9] libs/arm64-v8a/gdbserver
[arm64-v8a] Gdbsetup       : libs/arm64-v8a/gdb.setup
[x86_64] Gdbserver      : [x86_64-4.9] libs/x86_64/gdbserver
[x86_64] Gdbsetup       : libs/x86_64/gdb.setup
[mips64] Gdbserver      : [mips64el-linux-android-4.9] libs/mips64/gdbserver
[mips64] Gdbsetup       : libs/mips64/gdb.setup
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.8] libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
[armeabi] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.8] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
[armeabi] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
[x86] Gdbserver      : [x86-4.8] libs/x86/gdbserver
[x86] Gdbsetup       : libs/x86/gdb.setup
[mips] Gdbserver      : [mipsel-linux-android-4.8] libs/mips/gdbserver
[mips] Gdbsetup       : libs/mips/gdb.setup
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : hello-jni <= hello-jni.c
[arm64-v8a] SharedLibrary  : libhello-jni.so
[arm64-v8a] Install        : libhello-jni.so => libs/arm64-v8a/libhello-jni.so
install: cannot stat `./obj/local/arm64-v8a/libhello-jni.so': No such file or directory
make: *** [libs/arm64-v8a/libhello-jni.so] Error 1
```

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using Android-19 as runtime with an Android-10 device.

Put `APP_PLATFORM := android-10` in your `Application.mk` file.

Comment: i think libhello-jni.so is not generated

Comment: @Yoganand.N same error? This is IMO a simple API-level issue.

Comment: sorry, i dont get you

Comment: @Yoganand.N I gave a solution, you said "not working" so I'm asking if, with my fix, you are getting the same error `APP_PLATFORM android-19 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 10`?

Comment: What API level is your device? What API level is your `APP_PLATFORM`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66253/discussion-between-yoganand-n-and-shkschneider).